# How do I determine if a process is associated with a System.Diagnostics.Process object?

Tags: c#, process

Given a particular **System.Diagnostics.Process** that has been assigned values to its properties `.FileName` and `.Arguments`, what is the best way to determine if it:

1. has ever been issued a `.Start()` command or
2. is currently associated with a process at all?

If `.Start()` was never issued, then calling `.CloseMainWindow()` causes an InvalidOperationException, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried checking `Process.Id` and one of the Exit properties ?

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_members.aspx).

In response to poster's comments: perhaps you will have to wrap in a try/catch and an exception being thrown indicates not started?  It's not pretty!

Comment: `Id`, `ExitCode` and `ExitTime` all share the same exception, unfortunately.

Comment: The try/catch is what's working now and apparently what we'll stick to. :)

Comment: Can you update the answer to officially be try/catch?  I snooped into System.dll to look at the Process class and yup - there is no way to cleanly determine if the process is associated.  Ugly!

Answer (score 3):

If you're closing a process by calling `.CloseMainWindow()`, **wrapping the call in a try/catch block is the correct thing to do.**

Do this:

```
try
{
    process.CloseMainWindow()
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    // purposely do nothing here - the process exited before we told it to.
}
```

This is because checking the process properties before shutting the process down creates a *[race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition#34550)*: both the property check and the call to `.CloseMainWindow()` are racing to see which can complete first.

Consider this series of events:

1. The process is running
2. Your code calls `process.HasExited` and receives `false`
3. The process exits of its own accord, as it's finished
4. Since step 2 returned `false`, your code calls `process.CloseMainWindow()`, and gets an `InvalidOperationException: Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.`

No amount of speeding up your code, nor using locks, nor any other strategy can guarantee that the process won't exit after your `if` statement. There is always the race condition. So instead, use `try/catch`.

If you need to keep track of whether the process has ever been launched, you may want to wrap the process in your own class. You can use a lock when launching the process and set a boolean flag to indicate that it has been launched.

```
class ProcessWrapper
{
    public HasStarted;
    public ProcessWrapper(Process p, ProcessStartInfo psi)
    {
        // do argument and filename validation etc. here
        lock(HasStarted)
        {
            p.Start(psi);
            HasStarted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You could try and check

```
process.StartTime & process.HasExited
process.Handle
```

or perhaps use

```
process.WaitForExit
```

Comment: In the debugger, nearly every property including `StartTime`, `HasExited`, and `Id` are all showing the same exception and I cannot check them as a means to determine if a process is associated. `WaitForExit()` also throws the same exception.