# Error "Source: system process has exited, so the requested information is not available"

Tags: vb.net, process

It's works in my PC but when i put into another machine i got an error "source: system process has exited, so the requested information is not available" & the exe doesnt came out. Any experienced bro can help? Appreciated!

```
        p = New Process
            With p
                .EnableRaisingEvents = True
                .StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath & "\EXE\CDMObjectSelection\CDMObjectSelection.exe"
                .StartInfo.Arguments = strArgs
                .StartInfo.ErrorDialog = True
                .StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
                .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
                .Start()
            End With

            p.WaitForInputIdle()

            While (ginthwnd = IntPtr.Zero)
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
                p.Refresh()
                ginthwnd = p.MainWindowHandle
            End While
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this code in a debugger or wrap it in a `try/catch` block you'll probably find that the exception happens on the line `p.WaitForInputIdle()`. As [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1): this exception is thrown when the process has already exited. Try wrapping your call in a `try/catch` and dealing with the `InvalidOperationException`.

MSDN also says "If a process does not have a message loop, WaitForInputIdle throws an InvalidOperationException". Make sure the process you're calling has a message loop.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18479179/28037) for how to properly shut down your process.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you build your application on the right architecture.
For example, if you build your app as 64bit application and running on a 32bit operation system, you'll get this error. If you can, build your application as both 32bit and 64bit (Any CPU) and you won't need to worry about it.