# Is there a way to open an IE window with a user-defined name. When same URL opened, already opened IE window comes to foreground

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, processstartinfo, window-handles

Here is my requirement which I intend to implement. There is one window application showing some icons which take me to different web sites. When I click on one of the icons, it should open an IE window and append a customized name to it.

So, before opening any website after I click on website icon, I want to check if there is already an IE window open with that customized name, if yes, bring that already opened window to the foreground. If not, open a new IE window.

I have checked various questions posted which are related to what I am looking to achieve, but am somehow not able to get it right. Below is my attempt.

```
For Each e In shellWins
    If InStr(1, e.GetProperty("IEWindowName"), namedWindow, CompareMethod.Text) <> 0 Then
        hWnd = e.HWND   
        myIE = e
    End If
Next

If hWnd == -1
    Dim p As New Process
        Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(IEPath, webSiteURL)
        p.StartInfo = psi  'Trying to open a new IE window
        p.Start()                   

        For Each ie In shellWins
            If ie.hwdn = p.MainWindowHandle Then
                ie.PutProperty("IEWindowName", namedWindow)         
            End If
        Next
End if 

Else
myIE.BringToForeground()
```

This sometime works and sometimes does not. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I can't really comment on if there is a "better" way, but when you say sometimes does not work, is there any sort of determinable pattern?  Like if the target IE window was opened via this process or did the user open IE directly and navigate to the page?  Just and example, but pretty sure that type of info might help

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @Hursey. So, on few instances it throws exception at p.MainWindowHandle, "Error Description : Process has exited, so the requested information is not available. stack trace :   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainWindowHandle()". I happened to find out that shellWins is retrieving all the windows along with ie windows.

Comment: And to answer your query, IE windows are opened by this process only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work in which situation? Does there any error throw when it doesn't work? If there is, please tell us the detailed error information and in which line it occurs.

Besides, you could try to compare the url to check if the website is already open in IE like this:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim shellWins As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
        Dim explorer As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

        shellWins = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
        Dim SQuery As String = "https://www.example.com/"
        For Each explorer In shellWins
            If explorer.Application.Name = "Internet Explorer" And explorer.LocationURL.Contains(SQuery) Then
                explorer.BringToForeground()
            End If
        Next

        shellWins = Nothing
        explorer = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Yu Zhou for your response. So, on few instances it throws exception at p.MainWindowHandle, "Error Description : Process has exited, so the requested information is not available. stack trace : at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state) at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainWindowHandle()". I happen to find out that shellWins is retrieving all the windows along with IE windows. I believe while traversing through the windows retrieved by shellWindows, I need to put up a check to work for IE windows only.

Comment: Have you solved the issue with putting up a check? I find a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576848/error-source-system-process-has-exited-so-the-requested-information-is-not-av) which have similar issue with yours. You could refer to it. Please try to wrap your call in a `try/catch` and dealing with the [`InvalidOperationException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=netcore-3.1#exceptions).

Comment: Yes, thank you. After I had modified to:                                                                       "For Each explorer In shellWins
                        If explorer.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
                            If explorer.HWND = proc.MainWindowHandle Then" .           
Earlier, the error was thrown because user had other directories open and shellWins was reading 'File Explorer' windows too and proc.MainWindowHandle failed for 'File Explorer'

Comment: Great! You could put this as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.